# Graphics card and battery life on Dell XPS 17 9170

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, dell, battery

I have a Dell XPS 17 9170 for Linux, which has an advertised battery life of 8 hours. But the most I can get from it is 4 hours, while disabling unneeded apps/services and setting brightness to it's lowest.

In the Ubuntu 20.04 about section in settings it says my graphics are: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (TGL GT1), while the actual graphics card is - NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 6GB GDDR6. I believe this might be using some lower intensity motherboard-based graphics? I don't use the laptop for any intense graphics jobs. The closest would be occasionally watch 4K videos. But even that is not something I do often.

In additional drivers my driver is listed as nvidia-driver-470. There are several others available ranging from 470-525.

Is there a way to increase the battery life?

The command `lshw -C display`, gives the below output:

```
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: NVIDIA Corporation
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
   configuration: depth=32 latency=0 mode=3840x2400 visual=truecolor xres=3840 yres=2400
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:620-61f memory:ab000000-abffffff memory:6000000000-61ffffffff memory:6200000000-6201ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ac080000-ac0fffff
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: iomemory:620-61f iomemory:400-3ff irq:233 memory:628e000000-628effffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

Comment: Did you install tlp? Without it the defaults aren't battery-friendly

Comment: Check your firmware is up to date. If it isn't, update it. Also, check you have installed nVidia Optimus GPU switching support, or it will always use the power-hungry nVidia GPU.

Comment: I've set all the tlp settings to low and used nvidia-prime to st the graphics to intel, but it's still draining the battery in 4 hours.

Comment: Revise to that. I seem to have needed a restart. Will add details above.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments above, this has extended the battery life to 7 1/2 hours for me.

First install tlp, which is a utility to manage battery life on your system:

```
sudo apt install tlp
```

This can be managed by the configuration file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/tlp.conf
```

Which is fairly easy, but there is also a [GUI][1], which presents things in categories.

Here is my config. Go through to find the uncommented values that are larger number, see the above instructions to get the min-max values for your system, and change them accordingly.

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/tlp.conf - TLP user configuration
# See full explanation: https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html
#
# New configuration scheme (TLP 1.3). Settings are read in the following order:

# 1. Intrinsic defaults
# 2. /etc/tlp.d/*.conf - Drop-in customization snippets
# 3. /etc/tlp.conf     - User configuration (this file)
#
# Notes:
# - In case of identical parameters, the last occurence has precedence
# - This also means, parameters enabled here will override anything else
# - IMPORTANT: all parameters here are disabled, remove the leading '#'
#   to enable them; shown values may be suggestions rather than defaults
# - Default *: intrinsic default that is effective when the parameter is missing
#     or disabled by a leading '#'; use PARAM="" to disable an intrinsic default
# - Default <none>: do nothing or use kernel/hardware defaults

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# tlp - Parameters for power saving

# Set to 0 to disable, 1 to enable TLP.
# Default: 1

TLP_ENABLE=1

# Operation mode when no power supply can be detected: AC, BAT.
# Concerns some desktop and embedded hardware only.
# Default: <none>

TLP_DEFAULT_MODE=BAT

# Operation mode select: 0=depend on power source, 1=always use TLP_DEFAULT_MODE
# Note: use in conjunction with TLP_DEFAULT_MODE=BAT for BAT settings on AC.
# Default: 0

TLP_PERSISTENT_DEFAULT=1

# Power supply class to ignore when determining operation mode: AC, BAT.
# Note: try on laptops where operation mode AC/BAT is incorrectly detected.
# Default: <none>

#TLP_PS_IGNORE=BAT

# Seconds laptop mode has to wait after the disk goes idle before doing a sync.
# Non-zero value enables, zero disables laptop mode.
# Default: 0 (AC), 2 (BAT)

#DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC=0
#DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT=2

# Dirty page values (timeouts in secs).
# Default: 15 (AC), 60 (BAT)

#MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC=15
#MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT=60

# Note: CPU parameters below are disabled by default, remove the leading #
# to enable them, otherwise kernel defaults will be used.
#
# Select a CPU frequency scaling governor.
# Intel Core i processor with intel_pstate driver:
#   powersave(*), performance.
# Other hardware with acpi-cpufreq driver:
#   ondemand(*), powersave, performance, conservative, schedutil.
# (*) is recommended.
# Use tlp-stat -p to show the active driver and available governors.
# Important:
#   powersave for intel_pstate and ondemand for acpi-cpufreq are power
#   efficient for *almost all* workloads and therefore kernel and most
#   distributions have chosen them as defaults. If you still want to change,
#   you should know what you're doing!
# Default: <none>

#CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_AC=powersave
CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_BAT=conservative

# Set the min/max frequency available for the scaling governor.
# Possible values depend on your CPU. For available frequencies see
# the output of tlp-stat -p.
# Default: <none>

#CPU_SCALING_MIN_FREQ_ON_AC=0
#CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_AC=0
#CPU_SCALING_MIN_FREQ_ON_BAT=0
CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_BAT=2000000

# Set Intel CPU energy/performance policies HWP.EPP and EPB:
#   performance, balance_performance, default, balance_power, power
# Values are given in order of increasing power saving.
# Notes:
# - Requires an Intel Core i processor
# - HWP.EPP requires kernel 4.10 and intel_pstate driver
# - EPB requires kernel 5.2 or module msr and x86_energy_perf_policy
#   from linux-tools
# - When HWP.EPP is available, EPB is not set
# Default: balance_performance (AC), balance_power (BAT)

#CPU_ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_AC=balance_performance
CPU_ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_BAT=power

# Set Intel CPU P-state performance: 0..100 (%).
# Limit the max/min P-state to control the power dissipation of the CPU.
# Values are stated as a percentage of the available performance.
# Requires an Intel Core i processor with intel_pstate driver.
# Default: <none>

#CPU_MIN_PERF_ON_AC=0
#CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_AC=100
#CPU_MIN_PERF_ON_BAT=0
#CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_BAT=30

# Set the CPU "turbo boost" feature: 0=disable, 1=allow
# Requires an Intel Core i processor.
# Important:
# - This may conflict with your distribution's governor settings
# - A value of 1 does *not* activate boosting, it just allows it
# Default: <none>

#CPU_BOOST_ON_AC=1
#CPU_BOOST_ON_BAT=0

# Minimize number of used CPU cores/hyper-threads under light load conditions:
#   0=disable, 1=enable.
# Default: 0 (AC), 1 (BAT)

#SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=0
#SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT=1

# Kernel NMI Watchdog:
#   0=disable (default, saves power), 1=enable (for kernel debugging only).
# Default: 0

#NMI_WATCHDOG=0

# Change CPU voltages aka "undervolting" - Kernel with PHC patch required.
# Frequency voltage pairs are written to:
#   /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/phc_controls
# CAUTION: only use this, if you thoroughly understand what you are doing!
# Default: <none>.

#PHC_CONTROLS="F:V F:V F:V F:V"

# Disk devices; separate multiple devices with spaces.
# Devices can be specified by disk ID also (lookup with: tlp diskid).
# Note: DISK parameters below are effective only when this option is configured.
# Default: "nvme0n1 sda"

#DISK_DEVICES="nvme0n1 sda"

# Disk advanced power management level: 1..254, 255 (max saving, min, off).
# Levels 1..127 may spin down the disk; 255 allowable on most drives.
# Separate values for multiple disks with spaces. Use the special value 'keep'
# to keep the hardware default for the particular disk.
# Default: 254 (AC), 128 (BAT)

#DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="254 254"
#DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"

# Hard disk spin down timeout:
#   0:        spin down disabled
#   1..240:   timeouts from 5s to 20min (in units of 5s)
#   241..251: timeouts from 30min to 5.5 hours (in units of 30min)
# See 'man hdparm' for details.
# Separate values for multiple disks with spaces. Use the special value 'keep'
# to keep the hardware default for the particular disk.
# Default: <none>

#DISK_SPINDOWN_TIMEOUT_ON_AC="0 0"
#DISK_SPINDOWN_TIMEOUT_ON_BAT="0 0"

# Select I/O scheduler for the disk devices.
# Multi queue (blk-mq) schedulers:
#   mq-deadline(*), none, kyber, bfq
# Single queue schedulers:
#   deadline(*), cfq, bfq, noop
# (*) recommended.
# Separate values for multiple disks with spaces. Use the special value 'keep'
# to keep the kernel default scheduler for the particular disk.
# Notes:
# - Multi queue (blk-mq) may need kernel boot option 'scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1'
#   and 'modprobe mq-deadline-iosched|kyber|bfq' on kernels < 5.0
# - Single queue schedulers are legacy now and were removed together with
#   the old block layer in kernel 5.0
# Default: keep

#DISK_IOSCHED="mq-deadline mq-deadline"

# AHCI link power management (ALPM) for disk devices:
#   min_power, med_power_with_dipm(*), medium_power, max_performance.
# (*) Kernel >= 4.15 required, then recommended.
# Multiple values separated with spaces are tried sequentially until success.
# Default:
#  - "med_power_with_dipm max_performance" (AC)
#  - "med_power_with_dipm min_power" (BAT)

#SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC="med_power_with_dipm max_performance"
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT="min_power med_power_with_dipm"

# Exclude host devices from AHCI link power management.
# Separate multiple hosts with spaces.
# Default: <none>

#SATA_LINKPWR_BLACKLIST="host1"

# Runtime Power Management for AHCI host and disks devices:
#   on=disable, auto=enable.
# EXPERIMENTAL ** WARNING: auto may cause system lockups/data loss.
# Default: <none>

#AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=on
#AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=on

# Seconds of inactivity before disk is suspended.
# Note: effective only when AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC/BAT is activated.
# Default: 15

#AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_TIMEOUT=15

# PCI Express Active State Power Management (PCIe ASPM):
#   default(*), performance, powersave, powersupersave.
# (*) keeps BIOS ASPM defaults (recommended)
# Default: <none>

#PCIE_ASPM_ON_AC=default
PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT=powersupersave

# Set the min/max/turbo frequency for the Intel GPU.
# Possible values depend on your hardware. For available frequencies see
# the output of tlp-stat -g.
# Default: <none>

#INTEL_GPU_MIN_FREQ_ON_AC=0
#INTEL_GPU_MIN_FREQ_ON_BAT=0
#INTEL_GPU_MAX_FREQ_ON_AC=0
INTEL_GPU_MAX_FREQ_ON_BAT=350
#INTEL_GPU_BOOST_FREQ_ON_AC=0
INTEL_GPU_BOOST_FREQ_ON_BAT=500

# Radeon graphics clock speed (profile method): low, mid, high, auto, default;
# auto = mid on BAT, high on AC.
# Default: default

#RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC=default
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT=low

# Radeon dynamic power management method (DPM): battery, performance.
# Default: <none>

#RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_AC=performance
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_BAT=battery

# Radeon DPM performance level: auto, low, high; auto is recommended.
# Note: effective only when RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_AC/BAT is activated.
# Default: auto

#RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_AC=auto
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_BAT=low

# WiFi power saving mode: on=enable, off=disable; not supported by all adapters.
# Default: off (AC), on (BAT)

#WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=off
#WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=on

# Disable wake on LAN: Y/N.
# Default: Y

#WOL_DISABLE=Y

# Enable audio power saving for Intel HDA, AC97 devices (timeout in secs).
# A value of 0 disables, >=1 enables power saving (recommended: 1).
# Default: 0 (AC), 1 (BAT)

#SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC=0
#SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1

# Disable controller too (HDA only): Y/N.
# Note: effective only when SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC/BAT is activated.
# Default: Y

#SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=Y

# Power off optical drive in UltraBay/MediaBay: 0=disable, 1=enable.
# Drive can be powered on again by releasing (and reinserting) the eject lever
# or by pressing the disc eject button on newer models.
# Note: an UltraBay/MediaBay hard disk is never powered off.
# Default: 0

#BAY_POWEROFF_ON_AC=0
#BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT=0

# Optical drive device to power off
# Default: sr0

#BAY_DEVICE="sr0"

# Runtime Power Management for PCI(e) bus devices: on=disable, auto=enable.
# Default: on (AC), auto (BAT)

#RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=on
#RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=auto

# Exclude PCI(e) device adresses the following list from Runtime PM
# (separate with spaces). Use lspci to get the adresses (1st column).
# Default: <none>

#RUNTIME_PM_BLACKLIST="bb:dd.f 11:22.3 44:55.6"

# Exclude PCI(e) devices assigned to the listed drivers from Runtime PM.
# Default when unconfigured is "amdgpu nouveau nvidia radeon" which
# prevents accidential power-on of dGPU in hybrid graphics setups.
# Separate multiple drivers with spaces.
# Default: "amdgpu mei_me nouveau nvidia pcieport radeon", use "" to disable
# completely.

RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_BLACKLIST=""
# ORIGINAL: RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_BLACKLIST="amdgpu mei_me nouveau nvidia pcieport radeon"

# Set to 0 to disable, 1 to enable USB autosuspend feature.
# Default: 1

USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0

# Exclude listed devices from USB autosuspend (separate with spaces).
# Use lsusb to get the ids.
# Note: input devices (usbhid) are excluded automatically
# Default: <none>

#USB_BLACKLIST="1111:2222 3333:4444"

# Bluetooth devices are excluded from USB autosuspend:
#   0=do not exclude, 1=exclude.
# Default: 0

#USB_BLACKLIST_BTUSB=0

# Phone devices are excluded from USB autosuspend:
#   0=do not exclude, 1=exclude (enable charging).
# Default: 0

#USB_BLACKLIST_PHONE=0

# Printers are excluded from USB autosuspend:
#   0=do not exclude, 1=exclude.
# Default: 1

#USB_BLACKLIST_PRINTER=1

# WWAN devices are excluded from USB autosuspend:
#   0=do not exclude, 1=exclude.
# Default: 0

#USB_BLACKLIST_WWAN=0

# Include listed devices into USB autosuspend even if already excluded
# by the blacklists above (separate with spaces). Use lsusb to get the ids.
# Default: <none>

#USB_WHITELIST="1111:2222 3333:4444"

# Set to 1 to disable autosuspend before shutdown, 0 to do nothing
# Note: use as a workaround for USB devices that cause shutdown problems.
# Default: 0

#USB_AUTOSUSPEND_DISABLE_ON_SHUTDOWN=0

# Restore radio device state (Bluetooth, WiFi, WWAN) from previous shutdown
# on system startup: 0=disable, 1=enable.
# Note: the parameters DEVICES_TO_DISABLE/ENABLE_ON_STARTUP/SHUTDOWN below
#   are ignored when this is enabled.
# Default: 0

#RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0

# Radio devices to disable on startup: bluetooth, wifi, wwan.
# Separate multiple devices with spaces.
# Default: <none>

#DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth wifi wwan"

# Radio devices to enable on startup: bluetooth, wifi, wwan.
# Separate multiple devices with spaces.
# Default: <none>

#DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_STARTUP="wifi"

# Radio devices to disable on shutdown: bluetooth, wifi, wwan.
# Note: use as a workaround for devices that are blocking shutdown.
# Default: <none>

#DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_SHUTDOWN="bluetooth wifi wwan"

# Radio devices to enable on shutdown: bluetooth, wifi, wwan.
# (to prevent other operating systems from missing radios).
# Default: <none>

#DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_SHUTDOWN="wwan"

# Radio devices to enable on AC: bluetooth, wifi, wwan.
# Default: <none>

#DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_AC="bluetooth wifi wwan"

# Radio devices to disable on battery: bluetooth, wifi, wwan.
# Default: <none>

#DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_BAT="bluetooth wifi wwan"

# Radio devices to disable on battery when not in use (not connected):
#   bluetooth, wifi, wwan.
# Default: <none>

#DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_BAT_NOT_IN_USE="bluetooth wifi wwan"

# Battery charge thresholds (ThinkPad only).
# May require external kernel module(s), refer to the output of tlp-stat -b.
# Charging starts when the remaining capacity falls below the
# START_CHARGE_THRESH value and stops when exceeding the STOP_CHARGE_THRESH
# value.

# Main / Internal battery (values in %)
# Default: <none>

#START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=75
#STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=80

# Ultrabay / Slice / Replaceable battery (values in %)
# Default: <none>

#START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT1=75
#STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT1=80

# Restore charge thresholds when AC is unplugged: 0=disable, 1=enable.
# Default: 0

#RESTORE_THRESHOLDS_ON_BAT=1

# Battery feature drivers: 0=disable, 1=enable
# Default: 1 (all)

#NATACPI_ENABLE=1
#TPACPI_ENABLE=1
#TPSMAPI_ENABLE=1

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# tlp-rdw - Parameters for the radio device wizard

# Possible devices: bluetooth, wifi, wwan.
# Separate multiple radio devices with spaces.
# Default: <none> (for all parameters below)

# Radio devices to disable on connect.

#DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_LAN_CONNECT="wifi wwan"
#DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_WIFI_CONNECT="wwan"
#DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_WWAN_CONNECT="wifi"

# Radio devices to enable on disconnect.

#DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_LAN_DISCONNECT="wifi wwan"
#DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_WIFI_DISCONNECT=""
#DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_WWAN_DISCONNECT=""

# Radio devices to enable/disable when docked.

#DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_DOCK=""
#DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_DOCK=""

# Radio devices to enable/disable when undocked.

#DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_UNDOCK="wifi"
#DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_UNDOCK=""
```

Install the utility for switching between GPU and Intel graphics:

sudo apt-get prime-select

Set your graphics to Intel:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

Check what it's set to:

```
sudo prime-select query
```

Enable TLP as a service, so it starts when you star your computer:

```
sudo systemctl enable tlp.service
sudo systemctl start tlp.service
```

Restart your system for the change to take effect.

This has also made my system 100% silent, even when watching video, though it can't play 4K video. I guess you just need to switch to GPU.